# ExecuteSQL does nothing

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I am trying to fetch data from oracle database through Nifi.  In the canvas, I put "GenerateFlowFile" processor with a file size of 0 KB scheduled to run every 5 min.  This is just to trigger the "ExecuteSQL" processor on success.  For the "ExecuteSQL", I set the DB Connection Pooling Service to be DBCPConnectionPool.  I input the SQL query "SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE".  My DBCPConnectionPool configuration is as follows:

```
URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:sid
Driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Jar URL = file:///somelocation/ojdbc6.jar
User = someuser
Password = somepassword
```

When I tried to run, nothing happens.  The red box becomes green and there's a number 1 on the top right corner of "ExecuteSQL" processor.  But nothing happens. Then when I stop it, still the Active Threads is 1.
Can please advise me cause I am new to this?  Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the NiFi log files?

Comment: What version of NiFi? and how big is the table you are selecting from? It seems like it is hanging on the connection, or taking a really long time. How long have you waited to see if it completes?

Comment: Sorry, i was selecting from a very big table so i thought nothing happens.  I tried to query from a small table and it works, but the thing is, it keeps on querying the same set of records. how can i stop it to query if it's just the same set of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the original post is answered, I'll respond to the question within its comments:

You can set the GenerateFlowFile processor to run every 30 seconds or so, then start and immediately stop it. This will cause ExecuteSQL to run exactly once, fetching all rows.

Alternatively (in NiFi 0.6.0+) you can use the [QueryDbTable](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryDatabaseTable/index.html) processor, which will fetch all the rows the first time but then (based on a maximum-value column like an increasing primary key) only return rows as they are added.